# How to Tell if This Method Will Return True or False?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, for-loop

```
var stateCodeLookup = function (stateCode) {

   var states = ["CA", "WA", "OR", "NV", "NM", "AZ", "WY", "MT"];

   states.push("WI");

   for (var i = 1; i < states.length; i++) {

    if (states[i] == stateCode) {

        return true;

    }

  }

  return false;

}
```

I know `states.push` should add "WI" to the end of the array and change the array length to 9...But I'm trying to find out what will happen if a parameter is passed to it named 'state' that contains the value of "NM"

Comment: Why on earth would you not just run the code with "NM" and find out for yourself? How could it have been quicker to ask here than to just run it?

Comment: No you're correct. I'm just trying to learn for-loops/arrays.

Comment: Take advantage of the fact that if you are running a browser, you already have a javascript interpreter that is a keystroke away. :-) And I'm just talking about the developer tools, not even counting JSFiddle, Plnkr and all the rest.

Comment: `alert(!!{ca:1,wa:1,or:1,nv:1,nm:1,az:1,wy:1,mt:1}[ stateCode ])` is eaiser to code, read, and faster to execute...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find out by putting your function (and code that uses your function) into a program or service that runs javascript, such as [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z4s3u2ss/)!

Also, your code will return true.
It doesn't matter what you name your variable when you pass it in.

And, you may want to start your loop at `var i = 0;` so as not to leave out California.

```js
var stateCodeLookup = function (stateCode) {
   var states = ["CA", "WA", "OR", "NV", "NM", "AZ", "WY", "MT"];
   states.push("WI");
   for (var i = 1; i < states.length; i++) {
    if (states[i] == stateCode) {
        return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

state = "NM"
document.write(stateCodeLookup(state))
document.write("<br>")

land = "NM"
document.write(stateCodeLookup(land))
```

Comment: It's ok! Thank you for asking your question!